# How to install Standard 14 fonts in Red Hat Enterprise Linux?

Tags: linux, rhel, fonts

I am trying to install Standard 14 fonts in RHEL machine. How do I get those fonts in it?

Comment: Could you please add additional context to your post? Please update it with what steps you have taken and with what problems you have encountered. Have you looked over Red Hat documentation on how to add fonts? If so, please include where you ran into problems. Thank you.

Comment: TTF fonts : `# cp [font] /usr/share/fonts/TTF/` ... Or you can do `mkdir .fonts` in /home/name/, and copy fonts to the hidden `.fonts/` directory.

Comment: What "standard 14 fonts"?